# On installing phonegap, I am getting an error

Tags: node.js, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-cli

on installing the phonegap i am getting an error

```
npm ERR! Window_NT 6.1. 7600

npm ERR! argv " C:\\Program File(x86)\\node.js\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Abuzar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"

npm ERR! node v4.4.3

npm ERR! npm v3.8.8

npm ERR! path C:\Users\Abuzar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging

npm ERR! code EPERM

npm ERR! erryno -4048

npm ERR! syscall un link



npm ERR! Error:EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Abuzar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.stagging'

npm ERR!    at Error <native>

npm ERR!   { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Abuzar
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.stagging']

npm ERR!   errno: -4048,

npm ERR!   syscall:'unlink',

npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\AbuzaR\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\.stagging'

}

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

npm ERR!      C:\xampp\

htdocs\aa\npm-debug.log
```

Please help me here,

Comment: Hi Ather Ali. Can you give more information? It looks like you're running windows, which version etc windows 10? Doing a search for the error number found other people having problems, disabling the firewall while installing fixed it for [some people](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8048)

Comment: i am using windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.

Deleting `C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.phonegap.DELETE` fixed it for me.